# How can i use DisplayForModel to show different ViewModels on same page, when using paging?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have three ViewModels:

1. QuestionViewModel

Theese two inherit from QuestionViewModel

1. MCQViewModel
2. MatrixViewModel

I send a list of QuestionViewModel to my View and DisplayForModel renders the correct View, which is in the folder Shared/EditorTemplates.

This all works really well, but now i want to use paging, to show only 2 QuestionViewModel's at a time.

This is the paging class:

```
public class PagedData<T> where T : class
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Data { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfPages { get; set; }
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

}
```

PagedData would look like this:

```
PagedData<QuestionViewModel> data = new PagedData<QuestionViewModel>();
```

I add the List of QuestionViewModel's to the Data property of PagedData and pass this to my View.

What should i write in:

```
@model
```

or the View, To make it render the correct ViewModel ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself.

The way to do it is:

```
    foreach(var question in Model.Data) {
    Html.Editorfor(x => question)
    }
```